# How to add headers in specific pages pdfkit generated pdfs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, header, pdfkit

I'm currently using pdfkit in a 3.0.5 rails application to generate reports of user activity.
The pdf document is simple, first page it has some details about the user, a summary then
it has a table containing all the user's activity of the selected period.

First page is ok, but when I show the table the next pages must start with that header column titles in every page with the activity table header. (it remind a bank statement)
Something like this:

```
|user   |action   | source  | destination  |date-time          |
 xxx     1          1         2             2011-04-01 hh:mm:ss
 ....
 ====================page break=================================
 #after page break the column titles must be printed again

|user   |action   | source  | destination  |date-time          |
 xxx     5          4         5             2011-04-05 hh:mm:ss
```

Does anybody know how could I can do that?

Comment: It seems that this bug is related with wkhtmltopdf @ http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=9

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use some javascript to alter the contents of the header, but only on certain pages.

in your header html have a hidden div with your table headers, but your first page header by default. Then with a javascript onload function do something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function swap_header() {
        var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
        for (var i=0; i<pages.length; ++i) {
          if ( i > 0 ) {
            pages[i].innerHTML = '<table><thead><th>user</th><th>action</th></thead></table>';
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload='swap_header()'>
    <div class='header'>Normal 1st page header</div>
    <table>
     <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could also render out 2 different pdfs, and combine them programmatically with pdftk.